# 403 Error when Authenticating using tumblr gem for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems, http-status-code-403, tumblr

I have a ruby-on-rails application that wishes to utilise the tumblr gem for adding posts when an action is taken (eg: creating a blog post)

I currently have the tumblr gem installed and can manage to fetch my posts using

```
@tumblruser = Tumblr::User.new('myemail','mypassword')
```

However when i go to add a post where it asks me to pass the user information like so (according to the API for the gem)

```
post = Tumblr::Post.create(@tumblruser, :type => 'video', :embed => @post.video_html, :title => @post.title, :caption => @post.content)
```

it just does not want to authenticate and returns a 403 error

anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEW SOLUTION:
I have found recently that there has been a problem with the gem. So I have made a copy of it, changed a few things in the docs and code and put it at http://rubygems.org/gems/matenia-tumblr-api

Hope the changes and docs help someone else out there.
As always I welcome any improvements, or refactoring on any of my projects.
Kind Regards,
Matenia

OLD ANSWER BELOW

I managed to get around this by the way ... all i did was declare the username and password in place of `@tumblruser` like so:

```
post = Tumblr::Post.create(:email => 'user name email here', 
        :password => 'my password', 
        :type => 'video', 
        :embed => @post.video_html, 
        :caption => @postcontent)
```

where @postcontent is the html text of post.content and gsubbed to escape most of the html.

hope this saves someone else some time.

Comment: Your gem helped me so freaking much. O_O i just wanted to say thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to check authentication with any media like [Facebook](https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-facebook) , [Twitter](https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-twitter) ,[LinkedIn](https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-linkedin) ,[Tumblr](https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-tumblr) , [Github](https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-github) and almost 20 others (you can check [Here](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=omniauth) ) .Then `omniauth gem` is the first thing that comes to mind . Means It's clearly simplest solution for authentication and I love it